# What is the purpose of this AND gate in an audio amplifier

Tags: audio, logic-gates

I am analyzing the below audio amplifier circuit ([from 4D Systems](https://4dsystems.com.au/mwdownloads/download/link/id/337/)) and I am trying to figure out, what is the purpose of the positive AND gate ([SN74LVC1G08](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g08.pdf)) which connects to the audio input signal?

Audio input is PWM format.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can only guess, but it is most likely a buffer, both to speed it up and to reference it to the 3.3V supply going into L1.

If I were implementing something like that, I'd make sure that the 3.3V supply was exceptionally clean, possibly even regulated from some higher voltage for no other purpose than to provide power for that AND gate.  The reason for this is that the AND gate is essentially multiplying its supply voltage by the PWM -- that's why I'd make it clean, and that's why the circuit designer has put L1 and C27 in there.

Comment: How does this speed up the PWM input

Comment: It would speed up the edges if they were slow.  That may not be necessary -- but if you're going to use it to generate audio, feeding that chip with a good clean supply is essential.

Comment: @TimWescott  I doubt that making the edges clean is the purpose, since it immediately feeds into an LPF.

Comment: If the input signals rise and fall times are unequal it will cause distortion that a buffer with sharp edges will eliminate.  PWM has to have infinitely fast rise and fall times to well defines levels to eliminate distortion.

Comment: ...and the biggest component of that distortion comes in the degree to which the rise and fall times are unequal.  So if they're both **fast**, then there's less room for them to be **unequal**.

Answer (score 2):

The AND gate's inputs are wired together, so it is acting as a simple pass-through buffer.  This will probably be there because the source of the signal does not have a low enough output impedance to drive the RC filters that follow.  Furthermore, it may also act as a level-translator for the input signal.